# Divide one record with another in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

```
OsType  Type    count   P50 P99
Linux   Gen2    1635    39  159
Windows Gen2    1638    44  149
Linux   Gen1    1647    43  133
Windows Gen1    1687    46  138
```

I want to make a comparison b/w P99 of Gen1 Vs Gen2? how can I write a kusto query for it?

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. Based on [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator)

```
let t = datatable (OsType:string, Type:string, ["count"]:int, P50:int, P99:int)
[
     "Linux"   ,"Gen2" ,1635 ,39 ,159
    ,"Windows" ,"Gen2" ,1638 ,44 ,149
    ,"Linux"   ,"Gen1" ,1647 ,43 ,133
    ,"Windows" ,"Gen1" ,1687 ,46 ,138
];
t 
| summarize ratio = round(1.0 * take_anyif(P99, Type == "Gen1") / take_anyif(P99, Type == "Gen2"),2) by OsType
```

| OsType | ratio |
| --- | --- |
| Linux | 0.84 |
| Windows | 0.93 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QQUvEMBCF74H8h0dOrQTdNu3arvTsRdCD4GFZJGujBHdTaadoxR/v1IhQkJ25fAMfD%20YdHIHQoLXEuz84JLfD/fTmNgP1PrxoLI6teurGQGq38YE07srVL9T1DKkUWykwj7rxYfxQTFpdu5Ar6GxtSmhTM5V11LR68KHt3ge10CroomAq/rRlWvajFZesGSZj/k%20LWjVr61mrpNhdSUGQ4gvDeDza3n869JZ8xx30/FqbZOcrnIHsq3u0YfLPCf8WW0DTIMamuDhp5CrVeYr9hFjmNyBc9mpmAQAA)

###### 2. Based on [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

```
let t = datatable (OsType:string, Type:string, ["count"]:int, P50:int, P99:int)
[
     "Linux"   ,"Gen2" ,1635 ,39 ,159
    ,"Windows" ,"Gen2" ,1638 ,44 ,149
    ,"Linux"   ,"Gen1" ,1647 ,43 ,133
    ,"Windows" ,"Gen1" ,1687 ,46 ,138
];
t 
| where Type == "Gen1"
| join kind=inner (t | where Type == "Gen2" | project-rename P99_Gen2 = P99) on OsType 
| project OsType, P99_Gen1 = P99, P99_Gen2, ratio = round(1.0 * P99 / P99_Gen2, 2)
```

| OsType | P99_Gen1 | P99_Gen2 | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linux | 133 | 159 | 0.84 |
| Windows | 138 | 149 | 0.93 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QXUvDMBSG7wv9Dy+5aiXq+jXbSa+9EfRC8GIMqWvQzHky0owp7Md70taxwpKb55w8nCTvVjk41Ggbx/t9qxA9dS+/O7XonNX0ITEplmJt9uTEaqHJSTwXsxGqykMcBsswgF/iUdP+RzBJ8aAoFZDJPCsgs4qpqAZNildNrTl0YqKVkHnOlJ+06bSk1/I71jKmLLs8bdBKr829VobB6j4MHMLgiMOnsqr/Heoag+77G6MJXzyn1kTKInK4JPNLj9hZs1Frd20VNd/Kp/DmjzhPxhiGMITZXzjKY0v+28lgn+pUwjZOG25bzrqNkpsZrvwpbs+cNP4DQzlyb7sBAAA=)

Comment: See updated answer